# Crash while using memcpy?

Tags: c++, api

I am trying to copy file  from one location to other location using memcpy.

And I am getting a crash every time when the file path which I provide as source is non existing.

Is this a correct behaviour, if yes then how could I prevent the crash.

Comment: You are doing it wrong. How do we know what exactly wrong? You should have provided your source code. BTW is this homework?

Comment: Please provide a [short example](http://sscce.org). And I believe you're using `memcpy` completely wrong.

Answer (score 8):

`memcpy`'s purpose is not to copy files, but chunks of memory from one place to another. Depending on platform, I'm sure there are better ways to copy files between directories.

Answer (score 2):

No, no, no! What in the name of holy memory are you doing? `memcpy` is strictly used for memory transfer. For example, say you have a bunch of vertices in a graphics application that you want to give to the vertex buffer without actually passing a pointer. That way, you copy the entire array of bytes that represent your vertices and from thereafter - they are a problem of the underlying API. That's the intended usage. Also, be careful how you use it. You specify the amount of bytes that are to be copied. Make sure it is exact. At the lowest levels, there is no such thing as types, if you give it too much, it'll wreak havoc - tear into bytes that "belong" to other variables. If you're lucky, such code will kill your application. If you're not - it'll continue working.

For file reading/writing/copying, you have to consult standard C/C++ file input/output (or some more refined methods courtesy of the underlying platform, as one of the answers suggested). There's a lot of resources online, so I won't *reinvent the wheel* here. Hope it gave you a better idea of what `memcpy` is for.